# What's the difference between 話 and 話し

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between 話 and 話し?
Find it hard to differentiate. Anyone can answer?
Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Exact duplicate of both https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46459/7810 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19771/7810

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are using it as a proper noun or if the word contains an action (i.e. used as a verb). When used as a noun, the norm is to not add し in the end, and vice versa. You also do not include it before case-marking particles, as these always follow a noun. Some examples:

お話する , this is a noun turned into verb by adding する

作り話 , made-up story, noun

昔話, folk tale, noun

話が上手 , the "speaking" functions as a noun here before the case-marker

話し声 , means speaking voice, but literally refers to how the voice speaks and is therefore a verb

話し方 , way of talking, once again a verb

話し合い , this is a compound verb (to discuss) changed into a noun, but the function of 話し here is a verb. I think this should be the same in all compound verbs that start with 話し

Comment: この質問を読んで、動詞の話をフツー持ってくるかねぇ・・

Comment: もっと分かり易い説明があると思いますので、どうぞ、教えてください。